# PHP redirecting external site and POST json

Tags: php, json, post, redirect, curl

I am integrating a registration with another website. The other website posts my site some registration data in json, to a registration page on my site and prepopulating the fields. I take the user through the registration, then on success redirect back to the original site. This redirect is supposed to post some info back, in json format, the user ID etc. I'm not sure how to go about redirecting back and posting this data? I'd rather not use a JS form submit.

Any help appreciated.

```
//After I have registered the user on my site and it is successful  
if($success){

$postJsonArray = json_encode(array('success' => TRUE, 'userID' = 10));
$postUrl = 'http://thirdpartysite.php';
//somehow redirect and post this $postJsonArray to the URL

}
```

Comment: If you post an example, you'll get an answer for sure.

Comment: You can post the json using javascript (easier with jquery. Are you familiar with it?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible within PHP. You could use CURL to post the JSON to the other page, then do a redirect to that page, but you cannot redirect AND post at the same time.

For the CURL method, here is some sample code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$json = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

header("Location: http://example.com/redirect");
```

Comment: How does this work on the third party site? i.e usually when you post the data using a submit button or something, you are sent to a new page and can  use $_REQUEST to do something with the posted data. What happens when the data is sent with CURL and then you are redirected seperately? That POST data is not on the page that the user has been directed to, right?

Comment: Correct, the post data is not sent. This solution isn't going to be ideal in every case, but given the limitations, it's the best I've ever been able to come up with. You could also proxy the page content that is returned in `$result` and show it on your site. I don't know enough about the situation to say if that would work well or not, just another suggestion.

Comment: Well, I just need after registration on my site, I need to redirect to a third party site. I just need to let them know registration on my site was successful, and pass the user ID to them. It seems like a straightforward problem, but I can't see a solution.

Comment: The best solution would be a redirect page with a message and a hidden form that you post with JavaScript. You said you didn't want to do that, but I think it is the only way to do what you want. You could even do AJAX to your server to register, and respond with a message, then JS to post to the third party site, all on one page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PECL's `http_redirect` function.

Have a look at the documentation: https://php.uz/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php